# Blazor wasm slow to load first time

Tags: blazor

I made a really big mistake for a client, he only need a small website for it's marketing like 4 pages home/contact/about bla bla bla... And i though i would do it in blazor just to try it out. I initially though that loading time would not be an issue because it's a small website but it figure out that the app is like 12.3mb and it take like :

- 15 seconds on google chrome to load (first time) / 2-4 seconds after that until you reset your cache
- 7 seconds on edge to load (first time) / 2-4 seconds after that until you reset your cache

I tried Blazor Wasm prerendering but i have a lot of jsinterop for the animation so i don't know what to do to solve that **DO I HAVE TO CODE ALL THE JSINTEROP IN A JS SCRIPT TO BE EXECUTED INSTEAD OF THE JSINTEROP ?**

I also though about switching to blazor server but i'm scared of the number of concurrent users that can access the website. I'm on winhost and i have 300mb of memory i coudl possibly upgrade to 1gb of memory so i'm wondering if it's enough to handle like at least 1000 concurrent users.

I don't get the fact for exemple that this blazor wasm website https://bootstrapdemo.blazorise.com/ take me 3 seconds to load even when i reset my cache but mine take 15 seconds. I mean i only have 1mb more that this website.

Comment: Did you measure on a _published_ app?  12.3MB seems a bit high.  Publishing does some extra processing to slim down the framework etc.

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to tell what exactly is causing the performance to be "slow" without seeing any code, and you haven't provided any minimally reproducible code, but could you please provide the code so we can provide a better solution for you? In your situation what I would personally do when I'm out of ideas is to begin commenting out code line-by-line until the startup performance increases to where I'd like it to be.